# jQuery Mobile inside of a sandboxed iframe

Tags: jquery, mobile, iframe, sandbox

I want to run jquery mobile sites inside an iframe which is sandboxed but with allow-scripts. But it will show nothing.

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>#1 JS Scope</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">

<!-- Libs -->
<script src="../../lib/jquery-1.8.2/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script src="../../lib/jquery-mobile-1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.js"></script>
<link href="../../lib/jquery-mobile-1.2.0/jquery.mobile.structure-1.2.0.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="../../lib/jquery-mobile-1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
<!-- Page -->
<div data-role="page" id="home">
    <!-- Header -->
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="a">
        <h1>Top</h1>
    </div>

    <!-- Content -->
    <div data-role="content"  data-theme="c" id="frame">
        <iframe src="http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/" sandbox="allow-scripts" width="926" height="974"></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

It is sandboxed because I want to prevent the finished jquery mobile app having access on the DOM of the wrapping page. Therefore only allow-script is set to allow running javascript of jquery mobile.

But the iframe shows only white and I have really no idea what could be wrong. Because jquery should not need access to the parent DOM to show something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery Mobile tries to manipulate the browser history (history.replaceState), which isn't allowed when sandboxed

```
init: function() {
    $win.bind( "hashchange", self.onHashChange );

    // Handle popstate events the occur through history changes
    $win.bind( "popstate", self.onPopState );

    // if there's no hash, we need to replacestate for returning to home
    if ( location.hash === "" ) {
        history.replaceState( self.state(), document.title, $.mobile.path.getLocation() );
    }
}
```